# flutter : error when use Image_Picker on imageSource.camera PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

i am new in flutter
i use image picker package in flutter to get image from camera but i get this error when use imageSource.camera:

```
final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 100, maxWidth: 768, maxHeight: 1024);
    if (image != null) {
      listImageFile.add(File(image.path));
    }
```

this is my configuration of gradle and others in my android studio:

image_picker: ^0.8.5+3

Kotlin:       1.6.21

Groovy:       3.0.10

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021

JVM:          1.8.0_333 (Oracle Corporation 25.333-b02)

OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-bin.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

```
Flutter doctor output:

doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1741], locale en-US)
   • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\Flutter\flutter
   • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
   • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (3 weeks ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
   • Engine revision caaafc5604
   • Dart version 2.17.1
   • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
   • Android SDK at I:\android222\sdk\sdk
   • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
   • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = I:\android222\sdk
   • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
   • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
   • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 16.9.4)
   • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
   • Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.9.31205.134
   X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
       MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
        - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
       C++ CMake tools for Windows
       Windows 10 SDK

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
   • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
   • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
      https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
   • Dart plugin can be installed from:
      https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
   • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
   • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
      https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
   • Dart plugin can be installed from:
      https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
   • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
   • VS Code at C:\Users\masoud\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
   • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
   • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
   • Windows (desktop)                  • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1741]
   • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
   • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 99.0.1150.30

[√] HTTP Host Availability
   • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Please Help Me to solve this error

Comment: Do you have some code in your MainActivity.kt or MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

source:Imagesource.camera won't work in windows

```
import 'package:image_picker_platform_interface/image_picker_platform_interface.dart';
// ···
class MyCameraDelegate extends ImagePickerCameraDelegate {
  @override
  Future<XFile?> takePhoto(
      {ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions options =
          const ImagePickerCameraDelegateOptions()}) async {
    return _takeAPhoto(options.preferredCameraDevice);
  }
```